# Pimcore - Images not importing from csv import

Tags: image, pimcore

Hi i am working on pimcore.

I am trying to import object from csv.

I am Importing object by right click on the object folder and then import

All textual data are importing successfully.

**But only image is are not importing.**

Yes images are there in assets folder with specific path. its open in url as well.

**But images actually not importing in objects**

Please let me know where do i made mistake ?

Advanced Thanks

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately Pimcore's default csv import is suitable only for simple key-value parameters, mostly text based. For more advanced importers you should write your own - preferably in cli (https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Development_Tools_and_Details/Console_CLI.html).

You could also look for a more specialised plugin for your task, first here:
https://packagist.org/packages/pimcore
and also on GitHub (not all plugins all published on packagist).